# Asp.Net Core app deployed to IIS (locally) cannot read values from "Secrets-Manager"?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

When I compile my application using `dotnet publish -c Release` and deploy the application to IIS, everything is working fine. The problem arises when I attempt to retrieve values from the `Secrets-Manager`.

I ensure that my application on IIS is targeting "Development" mode, to ensure I am using "Secrets-Manager" and NOT Azure Key Vault.

I added a `Console.WriteLine` to the Startup.cs file to ensure I am in `Development` mode.

When I navigate to a place on my site where I need to retrieve the APIKey and APISecret from the "Secrets-Manager" it is null.

Here is my set up in `Startup.cs`:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Enviornment is: {ContextBoundObject.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}");
                      if (ContextBoundObject.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
                      {
                          var builtConfig = config.Build();

                          var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                          var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                             new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                          azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback
                        )
                      );
                          config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                        $@"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/",
                        keyVaultClient,
                        new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager()
                      );
```

I then retrieve secrets from the "Secrets-Manager":

```
string apiKey = configuration[nameof(VaultKeys.CloudinaryApiKey)];
    string apiSecret = configuration[nameof(VaultKeys.CloudinaryApiSecret)];
```

This all works when I run the app on IISExpress by hitting F5, but it doesnt work when I deploy it to IIS locally.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please provide details on actual behaviour as well as any exception that occurs

Comment: I think I ended up solving it. It kept returning `null`. Adding the `secrets.json` file to the root directory of the site fixed this problem.

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer? It will be easier for others to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to make sure that the ‘secrets.json’ file was in the same directory as the asp.net core project when deploying to locally on IIS.

Comment: It defeats the purpose of using secrets.josn, which is to prevent the secrets from being checked into source code.

Comment: How does it defeat the purpose if the question was for local deployment? This is for local “dev” testing. It allows me to deploy it without having to change any code

Comment: you can simply store in appsetting.json, why create different sets of files ?

Comment: What you are proposing is storing everything I have in secrets.json file inside app settings file, then when I deploy to azure adjust the code to pull from azure vault. With this set up I can use ‘config[“pass”]’ and this will for development pull from secrets.json and for deployment to azure pull from azure vault. That’s why I want secrets.json for local deployment

Comment: This answer shouldn't be promoted. This kills the whole purpose.

Comment: I believe you missed the point of the question. The point of the question was to deploy the app to local instance of IIS. Locally running app in IIS needs to have secrets.json file access. Were not talking about deploying app to production